# setNodeValue() method not working

Tags: xml, blackberry, java-me

I have created XML file for a Blackberry application ,and I have used

```
root.getFirstChild().setNodeValue("ABCDE");
```

to set the node value.

An exception is thrown while adding node value.

Comment: Publishing the exception would help, along with the XML you're trying to insert into

Answer (score 0):

I suspect (in the absence) of any info, that the `getFirstChild()` method is not returning what you think it is (a text node?), but rather something else. I would inspect the node returned (cast appropriately) and work from there.

Answer (score 0):

```
 DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory
                    .newDocumentBuilder();
            document = documentBuilder.newDocument();
            root = document.createElement("START");
            document.appendChild(root); 
//After this,I am trying to set the node value:
root.getFirstChild().setNodeValue("ABCDE");
```

Comment: I think you should edit the question rather than post further info further down the (albeit small) thread

Comment: Okies...

please help regarding setting the node values...really stuck

Comment: See the setNodeValue documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html), ... "The value of this node, depending on its type; see the table above. When it is defined to be null, setting it has no effect, including if the node is read-only."